# Proving $\sqrt x\ge\log(x+1)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

What is a simple proof that $\sqrt x\ge\log(x+1)$ for $x\ge 0$?

I'm trying to prove that $\sum_n\frac{\log n}{n(n-1)}$ converges, and my idea is to upper bound this with the telescoping sum $\sum_n\left[\frac{2}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt n}\right]$; some simple algebra reduces the problem to the one listed above.

More generally, it is true that $x^k\ge\log(x+1)$ for $x\ge 0$ holds, when $k^*\le k\le 1$, where $k^*\approx 0.37983121492657707\dots$. Does anyone know something about this constant or what bounds can be placed on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define

$$f(x)=\sqrt x-\log(x+1)\implies f'(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt x}-\frac1{x+1}=\frac{x-2\sqrt x+1}{2\sqrt x(x+1)}=$$

$$=\frac{(\sqrt x-1)^2}{2\sqrt x(x+1)}\ge 0$$

since $\;x>0\;$ , and thus the function is monotonic ascendent, which means

$$\forall\;x>0\;,\;\;\;f(x)\ge f(0)=0$$

Comment: Interestingly, this method only works for $k\ge1/2$, so the choice $k=1/2$ is in some sense "critical". For $k<1/2$, the function is no longer monotonic, and instead dips down in the vicinity $x\approx 11$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Do you mean $\;k\;$ is the root of $\;x\;$ ?

Comment: I'm referring to the generalized theorem $x^k\ge\log(x+1)$ mentioned at the end of the OP.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Oh, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Raise to the $e$'th power, and reparametrize bijectively by $x\to x^2$

$$\sqrt{x} \geq \log(x + 1) \Leftrightarrow 
e^{x} \geq x^2+1 \Leftrightarrow e^{x} - x^2 - 1\geq 0$$

It clearly holds for $x=0$. The derivative of the lhs is $e^x-2x$, the taylor expansion of which is $1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \text{positive terms only}$, which has a positive minimum at $x=1/2$ except for the positive reminder.

Comment: Ooh, I like this one since I have already proven $1+x+x^2/2<e^x$, so I don't need any calculus.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro How did you prove that inequality without any calculus?

Comment: @Joanpemo $e^x$ is defined by an infinite series, so you only need to know that the series converges to prove that. (You can debate over whether this qualifies as "calculus", but it is much easier to prove this than set up the general structure of differential calculus.)

Comment: Series is an integral part of calculus everywhere, as far as I know...and even a slightly advanced one as it is usually covered after basic limits, continuity, derivatives, etc. In my opinion, the fact that $\;f'>0\implies f\;$ is monotonic ascending is way more basic. At least where I am it is covered in high school.

Comment: @Joanpemo FYI I am actually doing formal mathematics here, so my "basic" is referring to "closest to the axioms", not "pedagogically basic". The theorem in question is [efgt1p2](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/efgt1p2.html), while derivative $>0$ implies increasing is [dvgt0](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/dvgt0.html). I suppose it's not obvious that the second one is more complicated, but it does come much later in the development (note the theorem number 10993, vs 17123). But both proofs are of course valid, since both relevant facts are already known.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Tahnk you, I see. Yet I all the time talked about " usually more basic ", "standard", etc. in reference to the order this stuff is usually taught in high school - undergraduate school.